# MatCheckbox has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy

Tags: checkbox, angular-material, angular9, angular-ivy

I'm trying to use the latest Angular Material with Angular 9 but I encountered below problem

and here is my app.modul.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule, CurrencyPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientJsonpModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { CollapseModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/collapse';
import { TabsModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tabs';
import { NgxPaginationModule } from 'ngx-pagination';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ServiceProxyModule } from '@shared/service-proxies/service-proxy.module';
import { SharedModule } from '@shared/shared.module';
import { HomeComponent } from '@app/home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from '@app/about/about.component';
// tenants
import { TenantsComponent } from '@app/tenants/tenants.component';
import { CreateTenantDialogComponent } from './tenants/create-tenant/create-tenant-dialog.component';
import { EditTenantDialogComponent } from './tenants/edit-tenant/edit-tenant-dialog.component';
// roles
import { RolesComponent } from '@app/roles/roles.component';
import { CreateRoleDialogComponent } from './roles/create-role/create-role-dialog.component';
import { EditRoleDialogComponent } from './roles/edit-role/edit-role-dialog.component';
// users
import { UsersComponent } from '@app/users/users.component';
import { CreateUserDialogComponent } from '@app/users/create-user/create-user-dialog.component';
import { EditUserDialogComponent } from '@app/users/edit-user/edit-user-dialog.component';
import { ChangePasswordComponent } from './users/change-password/change-password.component';
import { ResetPasswordDialogComponent } from './users/reset-password/reset-password.component';
// layout
import { HeaderComponent } from './layout/header.component';
import { HeaderLeftNavbarComponent } from './layout/header-left-navbar.component';
import { HeaderLanguageMenuComponent } from './layout/header-language-menu.component';
import { HeaderUserMenuComponent } from './layout/header-user-menu.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './layout/footer.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './layout/sidebar.component';
import { SidebarLogoComponent } from './layout/sidebar-logo.component';
import { SidebarUserPanelComponent } from './layout/sidebar-user-panel.component';
import { SidebarMenuComponent } from './layout/sidebar-menu.component';
import { ChatComponent } from './chat/chat.component';
import { Chat2Component } from './chat2/chat2.component';
import { CitizenInterestsComponent } from './citizen-interests/citizen-interests.component';

import {MAT_CHECKBOX_CLICK_ACTION, MatCheckbox} from '@angular/material/checkbox';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    // tenants
    TenantsComponent,
    CreateTenantDialogComponent,
    EditTenantDialogComponent,
    // roles
    RolesComponent,
    CreateRoleDialogComponent,
    EditRoleDialogComponent,
    // users
    UsersComponent,
    CreateUserDialogComponent,
    EditUserDialogComponent,
    ChangePasswordComponent,
    ResetPasswordDialogComponent,
    // layout
    HeaderComponent,
    HeaderLeftNavbarComponent,
    HeaderLanguageMenuComponent,
    HeaderUserMenuComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    SidebarLogoComponent,
    SidebarUserPanelComponent,
    SidebarMenuComponent,
    ChatComponent,
    Chat2Component,
    CitizenInterestsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientJsonpModule,
    ModalModule.forChild(),
    BsDropdownModule,
    CollapseModule,
    TabsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ServiceProxyModule,
    SharedModule,
    NgxPaginationModule,
    MatCheckbox




  ],
  providers: [],
  entryComponents: [
    // tenants
    CreateTenantDialogComponent,
    EditTenantDialogComponent,
    // roles
    CreateRoleDialogComponent,
    EditRoleDialogComponent,
    // users
    CreateUserDialogComponent,
    EditUserDialogComponent,
    ResetPasswordDialogComponent
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**ERROR in node_modules/@angular/material/checkbox/checkbox.d.ts:56:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.
This likely means that the library (@angular/material/checkbox) which declares MatCheckbox has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36060)

I was imported **Matcheckbox** instead of **MatCheckboxModule**

before that, I ran this command  **npm ci** I don't know if this affects but that what I did.

Comment: this worked for me
`import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef, MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';`
with 
`@NgModule({
   imports: [MatDialogModule], *MatDialogRef not needed here**
exports: [MatDialogModule],
providers: [
     { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} },
      { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} }
  ],`

Answer (score 8):

Add the file `package.json` in the `scripts` section as follows:

```
"postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points"
```

And run `npm install` or `yarn install`

Comment: "postinstall": "ngcc" and "npm install" resolved my issue. :)

Comment: I was getting this failure on a build agent (but not on my machine), so using the postinstall npm script above along with `npm ci` did it for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your import class should be ended up with **Module. In my case I was just importing MatFormField & stucking up with same error as stack's sub. Since I did MatFormFieldModule it works.

Answer (score 0):

To Fix this problem you need to clean your local node module cache.
Run this command to fix this:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Then reinstall your npm modules:

```
npm install
```